# SQL date_sub vs datediff performance in looking over a date window

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, where-clause, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to look at the number of active users of a product (toy example) over the last 30 days.

I'm considering two approaches.

One, `date_sub` is used to find the date 29 days before (the interval is 30 days inclusive of the start date) an end date. The `where` window is then defined by that earlier date and the end date.

That is this example:

```
SELECT 
    activity_date AS day, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS active_users
FROM Activity
WHERE 
    activity_date >= DATE_SUB("2019-07-27", INTERVAL 29 DAY) 
      AND 
    activity_date >= "2019-07-27"
```

A second approach is to calculate the `datediff` from a start date, then restrict the where clause to the previous time period.

```
SELECT
    activity_date as day,
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS active_users
FROM Activity
WHERE 
    datediff('2019-07-27', activity_date) < 30
      AND
    activity_date <= '2019-07-27'
```

I have no insight into which is the better option. I'd love for others to weigh in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first option:

```
activity_date 
    BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE("2019-07-27"), INTERVAL 29 DAY) 
    AND DATE("2019-07-27")
```

This compares the stored value directly to date litterals. Such an expression can take advantage of an index on the date column.

In, constrast the second expression applies date function `datediff()` to the date column. This makes the expression non-SARGable, meaning that it will not benefit an index:

```
datediff('2019-07-27', activity_date) < 30
and activity_date <= '2019-07-27'
```

Note that the first expression could be simply phrased:

```
activity_date >= '2019-07-27' - interval 29 day
and activity_date <= '2019-07-27'
```

I am unsure whether the second comparison should be `>=` rather than `>`. A reason why it would make sense is that `activitydate` has no time component. But I would recomment using `<`, because it works for both cases; if you want data up until `'2019-07-27'` included, you can do:

```
activity_date >= '2019-07-27' - interval 29 day
and activity_date < '2019-07-28'
```

Comment: Indeed. The BETWEEN confounds things here. Apologies for that.

Comment: @Learningstatsbyexample - `BETWEEN` is a shorthand for `>=` and `<=`; that is _inclusive_ of both starting and ending values.

Comment: I get this error: [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name. (195) (SQLExecDirectW) on MS SQL SERVER, how can I adjust the problem to MS SQL SERVER?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely use the first query, if you have an index on the `activity_date` column.

When you do DATE_SUB() or DATE() on constant values, MySQL only needs to do that calculation once before it begins examining rows. The result of the expression is a constant.

Comparing an indexed column BETWEEN the two constant values, then it can use that index to locate the matching rows efficiently, using a `range` search.

Whereas if you put your column inside the call to DATEDIFF(), it has to re-calculate the result on every row examined, and it can't use the index. It will be forced to examine every row in the table. This is called a table-scan.

You can use EXPLAIN to confirm this. The first query will show **type: range** but the second query will show **type: ALL**, and the **row** column of the EXPLAIN will show an estimate roughly equal to the size of the table.

FWIW, this is generally true: any expression where you put a column inside a function call spoils any benefit of an index on that column. Indexes work because they're stored in sorted order, but MySQL can't use an index on a column inside an expression or function, because it doesn't do any analysis to determine if the result of the expression has the same sort order as the column itself.